# Remove the bullets in Beamer's table of contents

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I use the `Madrid` theme

How can I remove the bullets in page of table-of-contents.

I have tried

```
\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]
```

It can remove the bullets in `enumeration` environment. But can do with that in table-on-contents

Comment: Do you want to remove the bullets *and* the numbers or just the bullets?

Answer (score 11):

You can set the `section in toc`, `subsection in toc` templates; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\hspace*{1em}\inserttocsection}
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{\hspace*{2em}\inserttocsubsection}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or simply, if no additional indentation is needed,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[default]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The solutions above will remove both the balls and the section numbering; if only the balls used are to be removed, but keeping the section numbering, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[sections numbered]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Test section}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\subsection{Test subsection}
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]