# How to change bullets to basic numbers in each tier of Beamer table of contents?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, numbering

I would like to have Beamer table of contents like this:

1. item 
   1.1. item 
   1.2. item
2. item 
   2.1. item 
   2.2. item

It is partially similar like this: [Remove the bullets in Beamer's table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54656/remove-the-bullets-in-beamers-table-of-contents), but there is no number before name of second-tier list item – subsection.
So how do I get numbers to all the points - tiers of table of contents?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}

\section{Baz}
\subsection{Naz}

\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is I wanted to get. But then I do not understand why command "\setbeamertemplate{section/subesctions in toc}[sections numbered]" looks like so, it should be rather only "\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]", because "/subsections" only misled me.